# Можно ли получить список открытых вкладок Google Chrome?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

Возникла задача посчитать количество открытых вкладок браузера Google Chrome на устройстве Android и получить их список (что бы собрать URL каждой вкладки).
Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли решить данную задачу и,если да, то в какую сторону копать?